# Python Scheduler not running at the specified time

Tags: python, scheduler

I have a job to schedule every day at particular time (let's say 11 am). I am using this code to do that. But it is not executing the job at specified time. If I try to execute it after every 4 or 5 seconds, it works. Does anyone know why it is not working when I am specifying a certain time to execute it? Here is the code that I am using.

```
import schedule
import time

def show_it():
    print('hello')
 
schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(show_it)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You aren't specifying a timezone so it's possible that the scheduled time isn't the recognized time. Either way, you should probably not be scheduling a python task like this. The infinite sleep loop is excessive for 24-hour intervals. You could instead use a TaskScheduler or `cron`.

Comment: [api docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-every-x-minute) shows you are using correct syntax to run a job at specific time once a day. If you run your python code at 10:59AM does the function not get called - what exactly is happening?

Comment: If you are running it on a different machine probably linux check the time on that machine. I happened to me once when I was setting for IST but the server time zone was configured to GMT.

Comment: @CodeMonkey- It is not executing at all. I tried to watch it for one day but it never got executed.